Using Spring Book JavaMailSender with OAuth2
Has anyone had luck with creating a JavaMailSender implementation to automatically handle token refresh/etc ? (specifically with Google OAuth2)
We could construct a JavaMailSenderImpl for every request, but that means handling configuration, etc... instead of using Spring Boot's auto-config.  I'm hoping someone has already done the lifting of making this straightforward (maybe by providing some sort of PasswordProvider callback or something?)
